# Adding same image to multiple tables causes reposition/resizing

Tags: libgdx

so I've been trying to bypass this issue by creating new image everytime i need to use it in that table and that works fine, however when I ported game to android and played a little longer, which means I went forward and back between menus that created new images everytime I entered them and I noticed that the frames started to drop the more I played.

So I don't know how to solve this problem, any help would be appreciated, because my solution by creating new images from the base image doesnt work

Code that I used to create new image:

```
new Image(drawable)
```

So does anyone know how can I use the same image that is created ONCE in multiple tables ?because when I add the same image few times in table it shows only the one that was added recently.

Comment: An Image can only exist in one time in the Stage. You can create multiple Images that use the same Drawable.if

Comment: If going between menus starts to slow things down, you definitely have some kind of bug going on. Not enough info to tell what it is. But an Image object itself is lightweight and cleaned up by the garbage collector.

Comment: @Tenfour04 But screen doesnt change in my game, I use one screen for the whole game, still you dont think its because I create new image each time i want to add it to table ?

Comment: Is the frame rate slowing down or are you seeing stutters?

Comment: @Tenfour04 i dont actually know if its frame rate or stutter, will test it tomorrow using android studio debugger to track frame-rate.But what happens is the game at least actors actions become very laggy